# Plotting multiple concentric triangles and polar plots, circles inside a Circle

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

**[image]**

for this code I am trying to generate above type of plot inside another circle by using numpy and matplotlib package functions and without using turtle.
Following is my code which I tried to generate concentric circles.I am trying to get concentric triangles or polar plots inside  the following code;

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200), np.ones(200)*5, color='r', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200), np.ones(200)*6, color='b', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200), np.ones(200)*4, color='g', linestyle='-')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an ngon by dividing 2 pi into `n+1` equal segments. Optionally you add an angle for the first point:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_ngon(n, rad, start_angle=0, **kwargs):
    ax.plot(np.linspace(start_angle, start_angle + 2 * np.pi, (n + 1)), np.full(n + 1, rad), **kwargs)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200), np.ones(200) * 5, color='r', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200), np.ones(200) * 6, color='b', linestyle='-')
ax.plot(np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 200), np.ones(200) * 4, color='g', linestyle='-')

plot_ngon(n=3, rad=4, color='g', linestyle='-')
plot_ngon(n=3, rad=3, start_angle=np.pi, color='g', linestyle='-')

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

The central and the right plot are generated by:

```py
plot_ngon(n=200, rad=6, color='red', linestyle='-')
for rad in np.linspace(6, 1, 20):
    plot_ngon(n=3, rad=rad, start_angle=rad/2, color=plt.cm.inferno((rad-1) / 6))
```

and

```py
for rad in np.linspace(6, 0, 50):
    plot_ngon(n=4, rad=rad, start_angle=rad, color=plt.cm.winter(rad / 6))
```

PS: To draw the equation `r ≤ sin(a / b * xs)`, following approach could work. Note that `xs` should have enough positions such that `a / b * xs` fills the full range between 0 and 2 pi.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)
xs = np.linspace(0, 12 * np.pi, 500)
a = 7
b = 10
rs = np.abs(np.sin(a / b * xs)) # or rs = np.clip(np.sin(a / b * xs), 0, 1)
ax.plot(xs, rs, color='fuchsia')
ax.fill_between(xs, 0, rs, color='fuchsia', alpha=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image: equation drawing]

Comment: Thanks JohanC  for the answer..can you help me a bit more   ....How I can plot multiple polar  equations in a single plot  inside the circles.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "multiple polar equations"? You can add any number of plots you want, the plot will just get fuller.  Can you edit your question above and add some example equations?

Comment: just wanted to use the following type of mathematical expression;  r <= sin(a/b)(x) where the x is the value  of angle with different values for a,b